# Google.apis.Oauth2.v2 Crash

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using Google Apis to integrate google in WP8 app.
I am using this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Authentication-using-cd382133).

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = App.GoogleClientId,
                    ClientSecret = App.GoogleClientSecret
                }, new[] { Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoProfile }, "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

Above code internally invokes browser and does login and should return to next line.

But I found that It crashes, within browser.

**Exception is:**

```
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserNavigationException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserNavigationException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.<AuthorizeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsyncCore>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SocialNetworking.GUI.GoogleLoginPage.<Authenticate>d__6.MoveNext()
```

**Issue logged**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense-api/p54fLjtUWVE

Is there any solution to this with using Google.apis library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding Google + Permission in App on dev Site.